# Gravity Form button to do two actions - Submit the form and another onclick action

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need to Gravity Form submit button to submit the form then go to another page with this:

```
</form><button id="btnPost" onclick="ukvd_submit_form()">Value My Car</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function ukvd_submit_form() {
    document.getElementById('ukvd_search_form').submit();
}
</script>
```

At the moment this code is another button but I need it on the Gravity Forms submit button to submit and do the action above at the same time. Is this possible?, thanks.

Comment: I assume this is Wordpress?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it is Wordpress.

Comment: Did the answer posted work?

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_submit_button/

```
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    return "<button class='button gform_button' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}' 
    onclick='ukvd_submit_form()'><span>Value My Car</span></button>";
}
```